# A euclidean number line, to a none euclidean one

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces

[illustration][1]

Hi,

there is a parameter in my algorithm that needs to exist within a certain finite domain for the it to be well defined, but it is informed from a variable that has an infinite domain. A diminishing return idea made sense to me in the context of it.

I was thinking, that this function function $f(x)$ that can spit out numbers to the domain $(-\infty,\infty)$.  In this exercise I would like, in a sense, 'normalize' 'hyperbolically', this domain to some arbitrary, but finite domain -$a < n < +a$ .  where the distance between each number gets infinitely smaller, perhaps at 1/b, to the limit of a or -a.

I'm currently on a trail using the idea of the $ y(x) = \frac{ax}{x+1}$
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjhrE.png

thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any context?

Comment: Whare are your ideas so far?

Comment: there is a parameter in my algorithm that needs to exist within a certain finite domain for the it to be well defined, but it is informed from a variable that has an infinite domain.  A diminishing return idea made sense to me in the context of it.

Comment: I was hoping I could find a lim x-> infinity g(x) = 0.5  and than multiply the number given from f(x) by g(x) but the procedure is escaping me

Comment: Hi, can you add these comments you've made above to the main post? These are useful information for answering the question. I think you may have to clarify your question further with others, but the above is very useful context, hence it's better if it is added to the question. Thank you and welcome to MSE and I hope you are able to address your question.

Comment: Thank you Teresa, will do

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'hyperbolically', and what $b$ is.

Comment: I was trying to appeal to the intuition behind the Poincare disk model of hyperbolic geometry.  Like the tiling of the 'angels and demons' where each figure is techniqually equal area, despite them getting smaller and smaller towards the edge of the circle.  The b was arbitrary, describing a rate by which the field compresses as it gets to a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect function for your use case is the tanh activation function and subtracting $0.5$. The function is
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}-0.5 \in [-0.5, 0.5]
$$
It is $g(x) <0 $ for $x<0$, $g(x) > 0$ for $x>0$ and $g(0)=0$ with $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}=\pm 0.5$.

It is close to $y=x$ near $0$ and flattens out when going to infinity. If you take a look at the graph of $g$ you will see that this function is pretty good for your task.

Comment: This is beautiful! Thanks, this solves my question

Comment: Great, I'm happy that I could help you. I would appreciate an upvote :)